# IF OR condition isn't working as expected

Tags: php

I have a for loop, but I want to skip some of the loops if a condition is met.

This works fine, and will continue the loop if `$option_nm` isn't "Fonts".

```
    if($option_nm != "Fonts"){

        continue;
    }
```

However, this doesn't work, and skips everything.

```
    if($option_nm != "Fonts" || $option_nm != "Style" || $option_nm != "Thread" || $option_nm != "Textbox"){

        continue;
    }
```

I also tried changing `||` to `Or` which does the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your condition is always `true`, not 1 OR not 2 will always be `true`.

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your current output?

Comment: What is $option_nm when you expect it not to skip?

Comment: @SethMcClaine Thanks but this is almost a year old post. $option_nm would be another value such as "Colour" or "Quantity". The project is long since finished with now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the `OR` statement.

Your code should be like:

```
if($option_nm != "Fonts" && $option_nm != "Style" && $option_nm != "Thread" && $option_nm != "Textbox"){

        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Of course! it has to not be any of them, not false for only 1 of them. I see what I done!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition always return true and loop goes continue, because your if condition you use `or` or `||`.
try this one.

```
if($option_nm != "Fonts" && $option_nm != "Style" && $option_nm != "Thread" && $option_nm != "Textbox"){

    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Even though your post is over a year old, I'll give another solution.

You can utilize the `in_array` functionality in php and do an negative if statement around your statement.

```
$elements = array("Fonts", "Style", "Thread", "Textbox")

if (!in_array($option_nm, $elements)) { continue;}
```

This makes future maintenance simple and is easy to read.

Comment: This will involve adding the items to an array. This was a modification to a complex system. A simple solution such as the marked answer was sufficient. I have used the same example you gave on other parts of the code, Thanks anyway.